# How to install canon mf4720w printer in 14.04 LTS?

Tags: printing, canon

**Is it possible to install Canon MF4720W printer driver in Ubuntu 14.04LTS ?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux right now, and [open this link](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/imageclass_mf4270#DriversAndSoftware), you will find yourself at a canon page where your OS is detected and it will provide drivers for your printer.

Having said that, I feel I need to add that in the past year I've installed several printers of several brands under Ubuntu including but not limited to Canon, Epson and HP, and of these though Epson was the most difficult to install, by far, Canon was the LEAST FUNCTIONAL when installed.  It was a Canon WiFi Printer in which the wifi, though detected, refused to obey commands regardless of whether the orders came from Ubuntu, iMac or Windows.

So if you run into problems, please return it and get an Epson or HP.  I'm happy to make specific recommendations if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings -> printer -> and new printer.

Comment: *add instead of and

Comment: You can always [edit] your own posts, no need for comments.